# How can I create inherited properties of functions without modifying the global Function.prototype?

Tags: javascript

Something like this works for the global Function.prototype.

```
Function.prototype.aaa = 1
(function () {}).aaa // => 1
```

But is there a way to put inherited properties of functions without changing Function.prototype?

```
function MyFunction () { return function () {} }
MyFunction.prototype.bbb = 2
// Can I have (new MyFunction).bbb ?
```

Answer (score 0):

Your only other choice is to create your own `Function` factory function, since you've ruled out modifying the mechanism used by the standard `Function` factory. And of course, that's unlikely to do what you want it to do, since everyone would have to use your factory. :-)

Modifying the `Function.prototype` isn't *necessarily* evil. [Prototype](http://prototypejs.org)'s been doing it for years, mostly to good effect.

Comment: @Raynos: :-) I would agree that modifying `Object.prototype` is **Absolute Evil**. Modifying `Array.prototype` is *fairly* evil because people get messed up on their poorly-conceived `for..in` loops (and telling them "but you're doing it wrong" isn't really necessarily a good answer). But `Function.prototype`? Enh... ;-)

Comment: @T.JCrowder Modifying _any_ native prototype is evil. I use `for in` loops on arbitary `Object`'s. I don't care whether an `Object` is an `Object` or an `Array` or a `Function` or a `Number` as long as it's an `Object`. So modifying any native prototype will break nicely structured generic extendable and functional style code.

Comment: @Raynos: I use `for..in` on generic objects all the time as well. We'll have to agree to disagree that *targeted* extension of native prototypes isn't *necessarily* a bad thing. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I guess you check `hasOwnProperty` in your `for..in` loops. I personally find it a chore and don't bother.

Comment: @Raynos: No, not most of the time. I don't use `for..each` on `Function` instances very often (and I venture to guess you don't either, 99.9% of the time).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Actaully I have a `Function` object which I set properties on an iterate over quite a bit. It's one of my main objects. I like the syntactic sugar.

Answer (score 0):

```
function Wrap() {
    var f = new Function;
    /* for (var k in Wrap.prototype) {
        f[k] = Wrap.prototype[k];
    } 
    return f; */
    // return $.extend(f, Wrap.prototype);
    return _.extend(f, Wrap.prototype);
}

Wrap.prototype.foo = 42;

(Wrap()).foo === 42; // true
```

Create a new function then extend that function with properties from your Wrap.prototype.

Either use jQuery, underscore or a simple for loop.

Comment: Are those inherited properties though? It looks like they are being copied to the new function. Underscore.js extend() doc says: "Copy all of the properties in the source objects over to the destination object."

Comment: @SamuelDanielson that's inheritance isn't it? Your copying them over. That's how it works.

Comment: No, copying is not inheritance. It's a poor second-cousin, and within the limits that @Samuel has set (not extending `Function.prototype`) it's probably the best you're going to do, but it isn't inheritance.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder The differences between copying references and setting prototype isn't that big. Inheritance just adds a bit of optimisation and scoping to it.